# jpa compare date when date are saved as long (miliseconds)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

I am using an external database and I can't use database-specific functions in my query.

`startdate` is saved as a `bigint` and is a [UNIX timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (milliseconds since the epoch).

So in my query I ignore milliseconds.

```
WHERE ma.conversation.room IS NULL AND (ma.conversation.startdate >= :startDate AND ma.conversation.startdate <= :endDate)
```

and my method sets the parameters thus

```
.setParameter("startDate", startDate.getTime())
.setParameter("endDate", endDate.getTime())
```

I know that this is very bad idea but I cannot change the database.

I do not know why i have got strange result in my tests ? for example this is my parameter for NamedQuery:

**QUERY StartDate :134 904 315 5000, endDate: 134 904 902 2000**

and i print out my list result and i have got:

query result : startdate=2013-10-01 01:50:23, startdate time=138 058 502 3863
......

Why that query brings me this results ??

1. though  138 058 502 3863 >= 134 904 315 5000  (true)
2. but  138 058 502 3863 =< 134 904 902 2000 (**not true !**)

**Question**

Is it a good idea to use the `>=` and `=<` operators?

Comment: Why would it be a bad idea?

Comment: I am unsure whether the OP _would like to_ ignore milliseconds in the query or already is, original phrasing: "in my query i am ignore miliseconds". I assumed the latter. I do not see how the above query ignores milliseconds.

Comment: @bmorris591 when i put parameter as startDate and endDate that date have got miliseconds set to 000 ... this is what i mean please look i edit my question